# Unhandled 'FormatException' exception when splitting IP octets

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to split the octets from an IP address input by a user and then place those octets into a text document. The problem is that I am getting a "FormatException was unhandled" warning. I am new to programming so I'm not really sure how to tackle this.

Here is example user input: `123.456.789`

And here is my code:

```
string fwrEdcgIp;
fwrEdcgIp = EDCGIPAddressFwrTxt.Text;

//Separate out EDCG IP Foreward octet
string[] edipf = fwrEdcgIp.Split('.');
int fwrEdcgIp1 = Int32.Parse(edipf[0]);
int fwrEdcgIp2 = Int32.Parse(edipf[1]);
int fwrEdcgIp3 = Int32.Parse(edipf[2]);
int fwrEdcgIp4 = Int32.Parse(edipf[3]);
```

Comment: Whats the value of fwrEdcgIp for which it throws an error.

Comment: I'd guess that one of the edipf[] values isn't a number. You should try step through the program line by line with the debugger and see which line the exception is being thrown on and for what value.

Comment: Did you realize that your bogus IP address is not an IP address at all and has only three parts not four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely one of the strings in `edipf` is not a valid integer. Perhaps the user input something incorrectly. When the exception is thrown, you should be given the option to 'break' and look at the line causing the issue and see what the problem is. If `edipf[x]` is malformed, then that is your problem.

I would use a `try/catch` block to catch this exception and inform the user to input the correct format. (Actually I would use I4V's solution and if `!ok`, inform the user of the improper format the user supplied, but it's still important to know this.)

```
string fwrEdcgIp;
fwrEdcgIp = EDCGIPAddressFwrTxt.Text;

//Separate out EDCG IP Foreward octet
string[] edipf = fwrEdcgIp.Split('.');
try {
    int fwrEdcgIp1 = Int32.Parse(edipf[0]);
    int fwrEdcgIp2 = Int32.Parse(edipf[1]);
    int fwrEdcgIp3 = Int32.Parse(edipf[2]);
    int fwrEdcgIp4 = Int32.Parse(edipf[3]);
} catch (FormatException) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please input IP address in the format "123.123.123.123");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using a real IP address parser (System.Net.IPAddress)?

```
IPAddress ipAddr;
bool ok = IPAddress.TryParse(EDCGIPAddressFwrTxt.Text, out ipAddr);
if (ok)
{
    byte[] bytes = ipAddr.GetAddressBytes();
}
```

Comment: i thought about this but i need the different octets to go in different parts of the document and did not know how to specify which values go where

Comment: If you want to use the `IPAddress.TryParse`, you may need to make sure you handle the user inputing IPv6 addresses correctly. You can easily split the bytes using something like `int fwrEdcgIp1 = bytes[0]`

Answer (score 1):

By design, `Int32.Parse` will throw a `FormatException` if the input is not a valid integer.  What else could it do?

Use `Int32.TryParse` instead for user-entered input.

Answer (score 0):

use TryParse as such.

```
int num;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out num);
if(result){
   // do something.
}
```